# First click on HTML links is not working!

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with a link in an HTML page where the first click on it is not working (I am using Firefox). The second click takes me to the corresponding link.

Furthermore, on the first click the parent element of this link moves a little bit upwards. So I assume this is a CSS issue, but since the problem is there only when clicking and not when hovering over the item, I am unable to see how CSS could be cause this problem.

(This issue is there with some other links in the page too, but with a different behavior: Clicking on the links changes the layout a little bit, but the first click itself takes me to the target pages.)

It is probably not a JavaScript issue because I tried disabling JavaScript in the browser with the same results.

(Sorry that I cannot post sample code). I just want to know if there is any known issue that may cause this problem.

Comment: You really do need to post sample code - otherwise your question is just too vague and open-ended.

Comment: Is it a Firefox only problem? Does it occur in other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if this issue occurs in every browser. If no - this is a browser issue.
2. If yes - check your CSS may be some problems in it.
3. If still can't find problem - put code examples here